# Hi, I am try to convert an array of objects into an object in typescript but the getting the error of undefined

Tags: arrays, typescript, spread

Input

`[{name : "Peter" , state:"California"}, {name : "John" , state:"Texas"}]`

Output

`{{name : "Peter" , state:"California"}, {name : "John" , state:"Texas"}}`

the code

`const a = List?.map((elem) => {`
`return { file: elem.file, url: elem.url };`
`});`
`// Value of a = [{name : "Peter" , state:"California"}, {name : "John" , state:"Texas"}]`

`const b = ()=> { Object.assign({}, ...a)};`
`//Issue : Type '{ file: string; url: string; }[] | undefined' is not an array type.`

Comment: Your output isn't valid JS - what do you need a value like this for?  Maybe there's a better way to approach that.

Comment: Hello scott, I need to access my data like this b.url should give the url. But all i was using ended up with the error. Can you let me know an easy way